# Can we delete the best-practices tag?

Tags: discussion, support

Can we delete the [solidity-best-practices](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity-best-practices) tag?

It's not allowed on StackOverflow
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275039/why-is-the-best-practices-tag-not-allowed
"Best-practices" are, more often than not, opinion-based."

Also https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Indicate your agreement/disagreement on this proposal with votes. Use answers to elaborate your disagreement or propose alternatives.

Comment: I share the same opinion.

Comment: Yep, agreed....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my recommendation for y'all.

I don't *think* you actually need to blacklist this because it seems like this tag is pretty much a subset of the [solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity) tag. *Most* of the questions that have it *also* have [solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity) already. There are [nine that don't](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity-best-practices+-solidity) which y'all can look through pretty easily.

Here's what I recommend:

1. Review those nine questions that don't have the [solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity) tag.

   - If the [solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity) tag would be appropriate, do nothing.
   - If the [solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity) tag would be inappropriate, retag the question to remove the [solidity-best-practices](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity-best-practices) tag and replace (if necessary) with appropriate tags.
2. Synonymize and merge [solidity-best-practices](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity-best-practices) into [solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity).

Congrats, you no longer have this tag and all of the questions that did have it still have good tags. This will also prevent someone from using it in the future, effectively blacklisting it.

I'm only recommending this in this case because there seems to be a clear redundancy. If this weren't the case, we might have to do something else to remove/prevent the usage of such tags, so keep that in mind in future cases where this may come up.